# Common development platform for Mobile or Hand-held devices

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile, frameworks, palm-os

Currently we are working on a project in which we need to come up with some framework or common approach to have single code base used for developing an application that runs in Windows Mobile and Palm OS (WebOS).

Is there any solution to this?
I heard of "PhoneGAP" but I am not sure how successful it is in current situation. Any one knows?

Any info is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been dabbling in this "mobile development" stuff for a little while now and my experience is that there really isn't any way to have common code between disparate OSes. WebOS throws a huge monky wrench into thing becasue it expects you to write your apps as web pages.  While that's all well and good, the code isn't reusable for the unbelievably crap browser in WinMo 6.1 and earlier.

If you target 6.5 only I suppose you could probably write your web app and do browser detection to determine code to run.  It would still get real ugly when you need to do platform/hardware interaction.  Unfortunately I think it would probably be faster to just write separate apps with separate code bases.